# Redirect all web traffic from specified program to localhost?

Tags: redirect, web-traffic

I'm trying to debug program that uses many ports (other than 80, 443) for retrieving data, and i want to create "redirector" that redirect all connections from (for example: example.com) to localhost.

Is that possible without directly hacking program? How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the program is running on your local machine, you could modify /etc/hosts and add the following line:

example.com 127.0.0.1

This will route all connections from your machine to example.com to localhost (127.0.0.1).

Comment: If i have Windows machine, editing this file: C:/Windows/System32/drivers/etc/hosts Will result the same?

Comment: Yes, it will do the same.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to edit your hosts file on linux/os x `/etc/hosts` and point all the IP's that your app accesses to localhost.

First though, you're gonna have to figure out what servers your app is accessing. You can do this with a tool like littlesnitch (osx) or even wireshark - though, wireshark method is a bit more involved.